# Radbaz on cross-dressing

Tags: sources-mekorot, clothing, gender-identity, gender

In *The Mitzvot: the commandments and their rationale*, Rabbi Abraham Chill attributes the following idea to Radbaz (without quoting him verbatim):

> It is understandable why a man should not dress like a woman, because
> this would indicate a degradation. But why should a woman dressing as
> a man be condemned? Is she not attempting to upgrade herself? He
> [Radbaz] answers that when two souls are lowered upon earth, one of a
> woman and the other of a man, God intended them to remain distinctive
> … Any change in this pattern would be counteracting God's design and
> is therefore forbidden, irrespective of whether it is upgrading or
> downgrading.

Can anyone point me to where Radbaz said this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in Metzudas Dovid, [Mitzvos 73 & 74](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47579&st=&pgnum=95&hilite=):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you